# Angular2 Routing Page Anchor Issue

Tags: html, angular2-routing, anchor

I am having an issue where I believe Angular2 is interfering with how it handles normal anchor tags in HTML. I have several links within the page under "Content2" with attempts in referencing sections of that page.

```
<div id="navigation">
  <a [routerLink]="['#section01']" fragment="section01" style=background:magenta>Section 1</a><br/>
  <a [routerLink]="['#section02']" fragment="section02" style=background:cyan>Section 2</a><br/>
  <a href="#section03" style=background:yellow>section 3</a><br/>
  <a href="#section04" style=background:red>section 4</a><br/>
  <a [routerLink]="['/content02']" fragment="section05" style=background:green>Section 5</a><br/>
</div>
```

My goal is to allow the navigation bar to serve as a navigation tool that sits outside of the HTML I am trying to call, but is still able to directly link sections within the HTML, in this case to Content2.

Here's the Plunker to my predicament:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/MFtSgY0e57nAG6D5

I have even tried to reference the HTML with a direct routerLink from the navigation bar but it will not comply. I'm sure I am missing something very fundamental to Angular2 routing. Or perhaps I'm missing how the routes should have been structured in the first place.

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: I added the code in question